# How can i find programs list with C#?

Tags: c#, regedit

l am writing a mini program with C# and l want to find install program on computer. l found an example but its not working %100

My Code:
ProgramName=CCleaner

```
 public static bool CheckProgram(string ProgramName)
    {
        bool status = false;
        string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";            
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
        {
            foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"))))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")).Contains(ProgramName))
                            status = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

When l running my program its not find "CClenear" but when l write "Java" its working. l am sure %100 CClenear installed on my computer. Java, Microsoft Office, Gom Player found but Ccleaner, Spotify etc.. not found. Can you help me where is my wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what do you get from key.GetSubKeyNames()

Comment: Could this be a case sensitivity issue?

Comment: I suggest looking at the registry with Regedit to see what is actually in the registry and why your search isn't finding it.

Comment: `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` is not the only location where installed software information is stored. On 64 bit windows, you will have the same branch under `WOW6432Node`. Also, the same branches exist in `HKCU`. Just search for the key `Uninstall` in the entire registry, and you can tell which all branches you need. Also remember that if your code runs as 32 bit, it won't see the 64 bit locations.

Comment: Yes Vikhram l dont see all programs in "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" How can l show add/remove program list with C#? l found this exam and it's looking only under "..\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" Can l search all regedit's records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might as well just double-check that the key exists. You could change your code to write out all the display names to a file, and then search the file for what you're looking for. The following code will save all the non-empty display names to a list, and then write that list to a file (specify a different file path if you want):

```
string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
List<string>displayNames = new List<string>();

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))
{
    foreach (string subkeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (RegistryKey productKey = key.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))
        {
            var displayName = Convert.ToString(productKey.GetValue("DisplayName"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName)) displayNames.Add(displayName);
        }
    }
}

var fileName = @"c:\temp\DisplayNames.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, displayNames);
```

Now you can open up the text file and find the exact name you need to search for (if it does indeed exist).

---

Another option is to do a case-insensitive comparison using the `IndexOf` method. `IndexOf` will return the `0` based index of one string if found inside another string, or `-1` if the string was not found. It also takes a parameter that allows you to do case-insensitive searching (and it also searches the whole string for your search term, not just the beginning).

You can do this in your original code by changing this line:

```
if (Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")).Contains(ProgramName))
```

To this:

```
if (Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
    .IndexOf(ProgramName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

Comment: Thanks your comment Rufus L, l think your codes also same result(l try and yes same). Vikhram wrote above. All installed programs aren't in "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall". For example Spotify registered an other place in regedit. l saw some programs and it's list all installed program. How can l list all installed program on my computer? Maybe l must change theory.

Comment: Some programs are installed per user. For those, you will only be able to see the ones that the current logged in user has access to. They would be under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: l used "using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey))" and "using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registry_key))" and solved. Thanks.